# jQuery: append and remove Elements?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to append items and then have the option to remove them.

I can simply append the elements using `append()` in jquery which works fine.

However, I have a problem removing them USING `remove()`.

to demonstrate this, I've created this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/q3Le48o8/1/

If you click on the book image, you'll see the elements are being appended properly but when I click on the elements, they are not being removed at all!

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: try `$(document).on('click', '.pricetag'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to :

```
/////append items//////////
$('.addons').click(function() {
   var names2 = $(this).attr('data-name');
   $('.Slevel').append('<span class="pricetag">'+names2+'</span>');
});


$(document).on('click', '.pricetag',function(){
    $('.pricetag').remove();
});
```

Comment: that removes ALL pricetags! use `$(this).remove()` instead of `$('.pricetag').remove();`

Comment: take a look in the code below, i did it , it's just i didn't save the fiddle link :p

Answer (score 1):

```
Hello i have fixed your issue please check below link
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q3Le48o8/2/